SteamApI does not see steam running
I'm trying to write the game using provided by steam example SpaceWar. Recently i haverenamed Visual Studio solution and now I always obtain message "Steam must by running to play this game". While actually it is running. What should i do make it see steam client?

manually put steamp_appid.txt to the folder with .exe
